# database not create in blazor using code first approach

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working with blazor and I am applying code first approach

but issue is my database is not created

[**Hierarchy Of My Project**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j05JX.png)

fist I create a project and then select a **visual studio 2019 -> blazor app -> blazor server app**

**then**

I add connetionstring in appsetting.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=userid;Password=password"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**then**

above connectionstring name initialize in startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
```

**and then** I create a Emp class

Emp.cs

```
namespace BlazorServerApp.Pages
{
    public class Emp:ComponentBase
    {
        public int empid { get; set; }
        public string empname { get; set; }
        public string empcountry { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**and then**  I create a mydbcontext class

MyDbContext.cs

```
namespace BlazorServerApp.Pages
{
    public class MyDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
        public DbSet<Emp> emps { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**and then** I crate a razor component(EmployeeList) in pags folder

EmployeeList.razor

```
@page "/"
@inherits Emp

<h3>EmployeeList</h3>

<div>
    <div>
        <h3>@empname @empcountry</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then run project but database is not created

[Output Of My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqQ8a.png)

**issue is database not created?**

help

Comment: Is this "Data Source=Desktop:000" your data source ?

Comment: @Biju Kalanjoor no I change the server name which place I am doing wrong help please

Comment: You should call database.setinitializer() in your dbcontext constructor

Comment: Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>()); will create the db if not exists

Comment: @B.Lec thanks for your suggestion Solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to nun the cammand "add-migration [MigrationName]" in the package manager(choose your project). Once the add migration command executes successfully, it creates a folder name as ‘Migration’ in the project and creates the class with the same name [MigrationName] as we have provided while executing add migration command with some name.

We have only created the migration script which is responsible for creating the database and its table. But we've not created the actual database and tables. So, let's execute the migration script and generate the database and tables. Therefore, executing the migration scripts we have to execute ‘update-database [MigrationName]’ command.

[You can refer this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/code-first-approach-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-ef-core-migration/)

Comment: as you said I am trying add migration but give an error see this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqc0U.png

Answer (score 1):

just add this in startup.cs in configure method

```
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Startup.cs

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
```

MyDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Data.Entity;
//using System.Data.Entity;
//using System.Data.Entity;
//using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorServerApp.Pages
{
    public class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            //System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>());
        }
        public DbSet<Emp> emps { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Just add this functionality in startup.cs page

Answer (score 1):

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

Please refer to the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-database

Answer (score 1):

You can first install the following package and then run your desired database by adding migration. Follow these steps:

first of all, install the following packages :

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

two add in Startup.cs :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

services.AddDbContext<Dbcontext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));
```

Then add in the Package Manager Console :

```
Add-Migration
Update-Datatbase
```

Comment: `Update-Datatbase` there's a typo should be `Update-Database`